# how to list the contents of a jar file inside a war file

Tags: jar

Lets say I have a .war file

myWarFile.war

This file has a jar file inside it - WEB-INF/myJarFile.jar

I want to see what are the files inside myJarFile.jar without extracting the war file.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

```
jar xvf thewar.war /path/to/jar/inside/war #extract the file...    
jar tvf /path/to/jar/indide/war.jar # read the extracted jar  
rm /path/to/jar/inside/war # remove it
```

I just did this and it did not delete the file I extracted from the war.  Please verify that though...;)

Comment: well that would be too simple :-) Let me rephrase my question with an example

$ ls
myWarFile.war
$ jar -tvf myWarFile.war | grep myJarFile
WEB-INF/myJarFile.jar

question is, how do I see the contents of myJarFile.jar "without first extracting the contents of myWarFile.war" .. is there a shortcut?

Comment: the 't' option means just show the contents, it does not actually extract the war.

from the man page:

 t    Lists the table of contents from jarfile (if f is specified) or standard input (if f and jarfile are omitted). If inputfiles is specified, only those specified files and directories are listed.  Other-
            wise, all files and directories are listed.

Comment: aah i  see. man i always read the question wrong.  You have a jar file inside a war, and want to see the jar.  In that case, extract only the  jar from the war, then list the contents, then delete the extracted file...

edited my answer above with all the steps...

Comment: yep..that works...i guess can't avoid extracting ;-) .. thanks anyways

Comment: @sunny8107 make sure you accept this as your answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the war in 7-zip you can open nested jars too.

I always use this script when I want to search or grep all the classes and other files on the classpath in a war (it does extract the war file though)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Unzips all the libs in a war
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
mkdir -p contents
cd contents
unzip $1
mkdir -p jars
cd jars
for jar in ../WEB-INF/lib/*.jar; do
  basejar=$(basename $jar)
  mkdir -p "$basejar"
  unzip -o "$jar" -d "$basejar"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A zipped archive (a .war is nothing else) contains a table of contents and packed files. There is no way of accessing the contents of any of the packed files without extracting them first.