# Linux command to display the contents of a file in a war file

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a war file on a linux server.
I need to display the contents of a file in the war file. Not just display what is in the war file.
I can display the contents of the war file using this command:
jar -tvf file1.war

I need to display the contents of the manifest file in this war file.
I thought I could use the pipe to add the `cat` command but it errors with:

> No such file or directory

This is the command I tried:
jar -tvf file1.war | cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

What command I use to view the contents of the manifest file in a war file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux command for extracting war file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3833578/608639), [One liner for listing contents of file within war file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23000741/608639), [how to list the contents of a jar file inside a war file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3238285/608639), [Seeing contents of war file without extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34533367/608639), [How to extract .war files in java? ZIP vs JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7882745), [Extract/See content of a specific file inside a .war file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37972850), etc.

Comment: Once the war file is extracted, I want to display the contents of a file in the war file.  So it requires concatenation of command

Comment: Yep, that is covered in the duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

I found something that worked for me...

> unzip -p file1.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing "no such file or directory" because the `cat` command can't find your manifest file. This is because the `t` option of jar only lists the files in the war file and does not extract them. Then, piping the list of files into `cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` causes the error message because the file does not exist because it was never extracted.

Try this, using the `x` (for extract) option instead:

```
# extract the MANIFEST.MF file
jar xvf file1.war META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
# cat it to the terminal
cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
# if you're sure that you're not deleting something important, then you can execute this to get rid of the META-INF directory:
# rm -rf META-INF
```